# how to insert rows containing sequential dates into a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, date, insert

I have a table which has one row containing the date, among other details, for each client. The table needs to have an empty row (except for the autoincrement id and the date) for each day projecting 1 year into the future.

I have tried PHP and sql but I am having trouble incrementing the date (CHAR 8 "YYYYMMDD"). I have Googled too. I hope someone will help me.

Comment: Why should it *already* contain a row? Shouldn't you add the row when you have, you know, some *data* to put into it?

Comment: Don't you think what you wrote is.. bad design? Why would anything have to have an empty row? Why would you insert dates in sequence? What problem does that solve that regular SQL sorting cannot? What problem are you solving? Why are you inserting a date into a `char`, which doesn't let you **operate** on your data, instead of appropriate field type that does let you operate on it? You just have way too many errors in there, and it leads to conclusion that your SQL knowledge is insufficient. How about you present your actual problem and we help with that?

Comment: can't you use date or timestamp data type instead of char? You would be able to do all sort of date operatins with ease.

Comment: Clients can ask for any date range up to one year into the future to enter or change details. Far easier and quicker to have all the records available than a patchwork  of missing rows some needing to be inserted and some updated.

Comment: So insert the record with the new date.. no need to make gaps in the literal meaning of the word. You have some other problem apparently, the one we don't know about. My hunch tells me it's definitely related to `auto_increment` and something people call "gaps". Just out of curiosity - am I remotely on the right track? :)

Comment: N.B. I have it sorted it was not auto_increment, it was the incrementing and formatting of the date. As I mentioned before, when a client fills in a range of rows with data we do not want to update existing rows and insert non-existing ones. With the rows created we only have to update :) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Business logic questions aside...

We can agree on a few things:

1. There are typically 365 days in a year.
2. There are 86,400 seconds in a day.
3. php timestamp() works in seconds.

Then this should help:

```
$i = 0;
$timeObjectForNow   = new DateTime(timestamp()); // Current time
$todayTimeStamp     = strtotime($timeObjectForNow->format('Y').'-'.$timeObjectForNow->format('n').'-'.$timeObjectForNow->format('d') );


while($i < 365)
{
    $secondsSinceToday = $i * 86400;

    $projectedTimeStamp = $todayTimeStamp + $secondsSinceToday;

    $formatedDate = date('Your formating here', $projectedTimeStamp);

    //Insert $formatedDate into your date column for the respective projected day.

}
```

I didn't test the above, its just to give an idea of one way to handle that.